# How to zmq.poll() some socket and some sort of variable?

Tags: python, zeromq, polling, pyzmq

I'm attempting to poll a few sockets and a `multiprocessing.Event`
The [documentation](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Poller.register) states:

> A `zmq.Socket` **or any Python object having a `fileno()` method that
>   returns a valid file descriptor**.

which means that I can't use my `Event` but I should be able to use a file(as returned from `open(...)` or an `io` object (anything from the `io` library), but I'm having no success:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1683, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1677, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1087, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\work\polldamnyou.py", line 122, in <module>
    p = poller.poll(1000)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\poll.py", line 99, in poll
    return zmq_poll(self.sockets, timeout=timeout)
  File "zmq\backend\cython\_poll.pyx", line 143, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll
  File "zmq\backend\cython\_poll.pyx", line 123, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll
  File "zmq\backend\cython\checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Unknown error
```

I have found the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764268/how-to-poll-zmq-and-variable) asked before but the solution was to use another socket which is sidestepping the problem. I am curious and want to see this working. Does any one have any clues what sort of object can be used in `zmq.Poller` other than a socket?

Edit: a few things I've tried

```
import traceback, os, zmq


def poll(poller):
    try:
        print('polled: ', poller.poll(3))
    except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
        traceback.print_exc()


class Pollable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = os.open('dump', os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY)
        self.FD = self.fd
        self.events = 0
        self.EVENTS = 0
        self.revents = 0
        self.REVENTS = 0

    def fileno(self):
        return self.fd

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item != '__class__':
            print("requested: ", item)
        return super().__getattribute__(item)

ctx = zmq.Context()
sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(sock, zmq.POLLIN)
poll(poller)  # works
file = open('dump', 'w+b')
print("fileno: ", file.fileno())
poller.register(file, zmq.POLLIN)
poll(poller)  # fails
file.events = 0
file.revents = 0
file.EVENTS = 0
file.REVENTS = 0
file.fd = file.fileno()
file.FD = file.fileno()
poll(poller)  # still fails
poller.unregister(file)
file.close()
poll(poller)  # works
fd = os.open('dump', os.O_RDWR|os.O_BINARY)
print("fd: ", fd)
dummy = Pollable()
poller.register(dummy, zmq.POLLIN)
poll(poller)  # fails
```

`__getattribute__` shows that that `fd` and `fileno` are being accessed, but nothing else, so what is still wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

> **what** sort of object **can be used in** `zmq.Poller` other than a socket?"

Welcome to the lovely lands of the Zen-of-Zero. Both the published API and the `pyzmq` *ReadTheDocs* are clear and sound on this :

> The `zmq_poll()` function provides a mechanism for applications to multiplex input/output events in a level-triggered fashion over a set of sockets. Each member of the array pointed to by the items argument is a **`zmq_pollitem_t`** structure. The `nitems` argument specifies the number of items in the items array. The **`zmq_pollitem_t`** structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    void //*socket//;
    int //fd//;
    short //events//;
    short //revents//;
} zmq_pollitem_t;
```

> For each `zmq_pollitem_t` item, `zmq_poll()` shall examine either the ØMQ socket referenced by socket or the standard socket specified by the file descriptor `fd`, for the event(s) specified in events. If both socket and `fd` are set in a single `zmq_pollitem_t`, the ØMQ socket referenced by socket shall take precedence and the value of `fd` shall be ignored.
>
> For each `zmq_pollitem_t` item, `zmq_poll()` shall first clear the `revents` member, and then indicate any requested events that have occurred by setting the bit corresponding to the event condition in the `revents` member.
>
> If none of the requested events have occurred on any `zmq_pollitem_t` item, `zmq_poll()` shall wait `timeout` milliseconds for an event to occur on any of the requested items. If the value of timeout is 0, `zmq_poll()` shall return immediately. If the value of `timeout` is -1, `zmq_poll()` shall block indefinitely until a requested event has occurred on at least one `zmq_pollitem_t`.

Last, but not least, the API is explicit in warning about implementation:

> The **`zmq_poll()`** function ***may be*** implemented or emulated using operating system interfaces other than `poll()`, and ***as such may be** subject to the **limits of those interfaces in ways not defined in this documentation***.

---

### Solution

For any wished-to-have-*`poll()`*-ed object, that does not conform to the given mandatory property of having an ordinary `fd`-filedescriptor, implement a such mandatory property mediating-proxy, meeting the published API-specifications or do not use it with `zmq_poll()` for successful API calls.

There is no third option.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the `fd` do objects returned by `open()` not have a `fd`? or is this a windows/linux thing(I'm on windows)?

Comment: For details see *Doc.*: https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.fileno and API doc --- "*The returned file descriptor is intended for use with a `poll` or similar system call only. **Applications must never attempt to read or write data to it directly, neither should they try to close it**.*" ( On POSIX compliant O/S `.getsockopt( zmq.FD )` yields `int`, may yield a `SOCKET` on Windows ).

Comment: I still dont seem to understand, the gile object returned by `open` has the required `fileno` which returns an `fd`. I even tried using `os.open` which returns just an `fd` passing it straight or as part of an object as a `fileno` method or `fd` property and still nothing

Comment: The API since version 2.0 until today **defines** *one and only one* **reason** for **`zmq_poll()`** to throw an Exception **`::= { ETERM | EFAULT | EINTR }`**. Write a **M**-inimum **C**-omplete **V**-erifiable **E**-example **code, that represents** your **problem** and either prove or disprove the root cause of the problem to be the `pyzmq`-wrapper `.poll()` method's API (in)compatibility - which is impossible to be done as you did not post a SLOC so far, or you might find an other root-cause of that *( in case the `.poll()`-method was not the one, who threw the above depicted Exception )*

Comment: any clues? i still cant seem to figure this out